# PDFTK extract all pages from all pdf's output

Tags: pdf, extract, pdftk

I'm trying to extract all pages of several pdf's at the same time.

Now it does work with:

`for %%I in (*.pdf) do "pdftk.exe" "%%I" burst`

But I don't get all the pages, because for every new document he overwrites previous extracted pages.

So I tried:

`for %%I in (*.pdf) do "pdftk.exe" "%%I" burst output "%%~nI_%02d.pdf"`

But then it doenst work at all...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to burst all PDF files of the current directory into numbered single-page PDF files:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%F in (*.pdf) do call :burst "%%F"

goto xit

:burst
set name=%1
if not [%name:~1,5%]==[burst] (
  pdftk %1 burst output "burst_%~n1_%%04d.pdf"
  for %%d in (doc_data.txt) do del %%d
)
goto :EOF

:xit
pause
endlocal
```

The script prepends `"burst_"` to all generated filenames to avoid a clash between the original `PDF` files and the newly created ones. `%%04d` tells `pdftk` to add the page number as four digits with leading zeroes. Double `%` is needed to escape the CMD shell.